# CSS - Style sheet that is called last isn't overriding/important

Tags: css

I'm writing a jQuery script that helps make old sites responsive by applying a fluid grid system to them.

It's all working pretty well, except for a few things. Firstly, the plugin and stylesheet are called at the end of the page so the CSS styles SHOULD override whatever else is on the page. However (I think this is due to specificity) when I have:

```
<div id="header" class="span4">

#header {
float: right;
width: 960px;
margin-left: -5em;
}

[class*="span"] {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
}
```

The `#header` styles take precedence, even though the `.span` styles are lower in CSS. I know it's generally seen as bad form, but is the best/only way to combat this to add `!important` to each style from my plugin's stylesheet? They **are** important and the whole point of using the plugin is to override your current stylesheet, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: `#header` is more **specific** than `[class*="span"]`, so the latter won't be applied.

Comment: I'm aware. As noted, this plugin is for people who've already designed/built sites and want to make them responsive, so the classes should override any of their pre-existing styles. Hence why I want to know if adding `!important` is my only option to have them take precedence.

Comment: Why not just add styles inline (this is what most libraries do)?

Comment: This seems a bit clunky though, considering there are about 900 lines of responsive css being added - this would make my js file huge and unmanageable! Plus there's a lot of adding/removing classes in the javascript. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An imperfect solution would be to wrap the inner html of the body tag with 2-4 div's with different id's, so that the css from the fluid css file is more specific:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper_1">
            <div id="wrapper_2">
                <div id="wrapper_3">
                    <div id="header" class="span4">
                        This is set as red by the main css file, but is rendered as blue, because the fluid css file has more specific declarations.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* MAIN CSS FILE */
#header {
color: red;
}

/* END MAIN CSS FILE */

/* FLUID CSS FILE */
#wrapper_1 #wrapper_2 #wrapper_3 [class*="span"] {
color: blue;
}

/* END FLUID CSS FILE */
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j5gt7/

For more info you can read http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

This solutions isn't perfect because the element could have inline styles, or the main css may have selectors with even more then 2-4 IDs which will override the fluid css (or rules set with !important).

Comment: This is a good idea - however, if there already is an ID on the body/html then this will mess things up won't it? Do you think a better solution would be to add inline styles instead of classes as suggested in the comments to the OP?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have lots of div's with class="span4", class="span6" etc., so just adding inline styles would make a mess. You are right about the problem if there is a preset id on the html and/or body tag, a fix for that would be to just wrap the inner html of body with 2-4 divs
<div id="wrapper_1">
    <div id="wrapper_2">
        <div id="wrapper_3">
            <div id="header" class="span4">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> http://jsfiddle.net/j5gt7/

Comment: This is a great idea, cheers! Maybe add it to your original answer to help others who come across it.